# Multiple changes in state are not altering the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

(Sorry my english, i used google translate ) In my code I have several iterations and in each one of them I change a text to be displayed on screen:

```
export function MyScreen() {
  const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState('');
  async function sync() {
    setCurrentText('Sending configs') 
    await ConfigurationService.sync();
    setCurrentText('Sending clients')
    await ClientService.sync();
    setCurrentText('Fetching data for local sync')
    await api.get('http://myserver/get').then(async ({ data }) => {
        await syncClients(data);
        await syncProducts(data);
        //... call from other functions that also change setCurrentText
        setCurrentText('Sync finished');
        return true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        setCurrentText('Sync failed');
        return false;
    });
  }

  async function syncClients(data) {
    setCurrentText('Sync local clients');
    // data.clients.new, data.clients.updated and data.clients.excluded is a long array
    if (data.clients) {
        if (data.clients.new) {
            setCurrentText(`Updating ${data.clients.new.length} clients`);
            for (let client of data.clients.new) {
                ClientRepository.save(client);
            }
        }
        if (data.clients.updated) {
            setCurrentText(`Updating ${data.clients.updated.length} clients`);
            for (let client of data.clients.updated) {
                ClientRepository.save(client );
            }
        }
        if (data.clients.excluded) {
            setCurrentText(`Excluding ${data.clients.excluded.length} clients`);
            for (let client of data.clients.excluded) {
                ClientRepository.delete(client);
            }
        }
    }
  }
  async function syncProducts(data) {
    setCurrentText('Sync local products');
    // data.products.new, data.products.updated and data.products.excluded is a long array
    if (data.products) {
        if (data.products.new) {
            setCurrentText(`Saving ${data.products.new.length} products`);
            for (let product of data.products.new) {
                ProductRepository.save(product);
            }
        }
        if (data.products.updated) {
            setCurrentText(`Updating ${data.products.updated.length} products`);
            for (let product of data.products.updated) {
                ProductRepository.save(product);
            }
        }
        if (data.products.excluded) {
            setCurrentText(`Excluding ${data.products.excluded.length} products`);
            for (let product of data.products.excluded) {
                ProductRepository.delete(product);
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={sync}>
        <Text>PRESS TO SYNC</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{currentText}</Text>
    </View
  );
}
```

It turns out that the currentText variable is only being updated the first three times and then it already updates with the last text 'Sync finished'. Updates that are triggered in other functions are not updating the screen.
Has anyone ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because the `syncClients` and `syncProducts` functions are not asynchronous.
React takes all the state changes that have been done in a synchronous cycle and takes the latest output.

### Example:

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
setText('first line');
setText('second line');
}, []);
```

This will set the `text` value to 'second line', since that is the last value within the cycle that is set using the `setText` function.

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

useEffect(async () => {
setText('first line');
await delay(1000);
setText('second line');
}, []);
```

Since this is async, it will first set the text to 'first line' and render this. After the delay it will set the text to 'second line'.

Comment: even with async it didn't work. A text only updated in last set... updated my question

Comment: This is because even though you made it async, it is not awaiting anything. What is the reason you want to have the text set to these value's in between? The data will be processed within milliseconds which means that no user will ever see it.

Comment: the text changes don't happen in milliseconds because each function takes more than 20 seconds to execute because the operations I do are in Realm and they take a certain time when the list is big, as it is in my case